# Make checkboxs disabled during page load

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have checkboxes in my form.

During page load whenever i clicked on the checkboxes it checked,but i dont want this during page load the checkboxes should be disabled or not clickable but after page complete load it must be oprational how to solve this problem any one have idea kindly share

Comment: Could you please post your code? Thanks

Comment: simple checkbox code as usual we used but i have loaded form it takes sometime to load and during this load the checkboxes which is already disabled though script also checkable @Christos

Comment: Instead of disabling all checkboxes, why not draw an element over the page during page load, preventing the checkboxes from being clicked.

Comment: @Mouser yeah i like ur idea but how to do that

Comment: @WaqasKhan my solution is up.

Comment: @Mouser please share any code

Comment: @WaqasKhan I've posted a solution 9 minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

just add disabled="disabled" on all checkbox inputs and then remove it on document load. for example using jquery:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]'). removeProp("disabled");
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Vick you were faster, same solution i guess

Answer (score 1):

Too much jQuery in here:

Plain (vanilla) JavaScript:

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", function(){
     var checkBoxElements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for (var i = 0, i < checkBoxElements.length; ++i)
    {
         checkBoxElements[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
    }

}, false);
```

Providing the checkbox is disabled in the first place.

---

**My other solution**:  Put a div element over the entire page blocking the user from clicking on an element during page load. You can also position this over the form element during page load to make the other part of the page accessible during page load.

```
<div id="blocker"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#blocker {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", function(){
     document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("blocker"));
}, false);
```

**Enhanced** block only form/container, not whole page

```
function formElementDisabler(node)
{
    //provide a form element or other container
    //get dimensions:
    var width = node.offsetWidth;
    var height = node.offsetHeight;
    var left = node.offsetLeft;
    var top = node.offsetTop;

    var clonedBlocker = document.getElementById("blocker").cloneNode();
    clonedBlocker.className = "blocker";
    clonedBlocker.removeAttribute("id");

    clonedBlocker.style.left = left + "px";
    clonedBlocker.style.top = top + "px";
    clonedBlocker.style.width = width + "px";
    clonedBlocker.style.height = height + "px";
    clonedBlocker.style.zIndex = "1000";

    if (node.parentElement)
    {
        node.parentElement.appendChild(clonedBlocker);
    }
    else
    {
        document.body.appendChild(clonedBlocker);
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var blockers = document.querySelectorAll(".blocker");
    for (var i = 0, i < blockers.length; ++i)
    {
        blockers[i].parentElement.removeChild(blockers[i]);
    }
}, false);
```

```css
#blocker {
    display: none;
}   

.blocker {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This script has to be the very last in your body. It disables a container during loading. If you provide a node to `formElementDisabler` it will draw a div over that node disabling input on that element.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add to every checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
```

And then (assuming jQuery is in place):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(":checkbox").prop("disabled", false);
    });
</script>
```

or without jQuery:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");    
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
    if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") inputs[i].disabled = false;
```

Comment: This is a jQuery solution

Comment: @Mouser please share your idea how to do this as u discuss above

Comment: do you have jQuery included there?

Comment: yes and another important thing is that its not good to disabled the checkboxes by default @OlegDubas

Comment: what about if instead of disabling them and then enabling back, we just uncheck all checkboxes after the page is loaded? I can be a bit confusing for the user though, when he checks something and then it dissappears

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="checkBox"/>
```

and after the pageload, enable the checkbox:

```
document.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("checkBox").disabled = false;
};
```

Additionally the solution for jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkBox').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("checkBox").disabled = false;` this will only work for one checkbox. OP clearly states checkboxes. It works though as a proof of concept.